# Adding text to Sharepoint enhanced rich text editor using JQuery

Tags: jquery, sharepoint, rich-text-editor

I am working on a script that will insert a table in a rich text editor that is on the page. For this I have written the following piece of code:

```
$('#'+id).contents().children().children('body').html(value);
```

where: *value* is a variable with the html code for the table.

When I execute the code if I use alerts to check the html code inside the iFrame, it shows me that inside the body tag there is a table, the table I had in the value variable, but this table does not show in the text area of the rich text editor.

Have you got any ideas why? I've been searching the Internet for an answer for 3 days now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a [post on my blog](http://sympmarc.com/2011/05/25/setting-a-rich-text-column-in-a-sharepoint-form/) which shows how to do this. Here's the basic idea:

```
var systemDescriptionRTETextArea = $("textarea[Title='System Description']");
$(systemDescriptionRTETextArea).html("Cream cheese");
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That was really helpful. I managed to add text to the textarea but when I try to add HTML tags, the enhanced rich text editor simply ignores them. I tried adding a table tag and it didn't work and I came down to a simple <b>Testing</b> added to the textarea, but the result is a normal Testing text, not bolded. Do you know why?